# Every VS2012 launch reopens last "Unit Test Sessions" windows

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I use dotCover by JetBrains.

I try to close all "Unit Tess Session" windows and then close VS2012, but the next VS2012 launch reopens them again.

How to accomplish that?

Comment: How to accomplish *what*?  Do consider the vendor's support forum for the quickest help.

Comment: Do you use dotCover's test runner or ReSharper's? This can be caused by shared settings of the tools in case you use both.